# Hide container if DFP ad not loaded

Tags: javascript, google-dfp

I want to hide container based on google DFP ad is not loaded or not. I get Iframe body blank as shown below when ad is not loaded.

```
<iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/1009127/<id>_0__hidden__" name="google_ads_iframe_/1009127/<id>_0__hidden__" width="0" height="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom; visibility: hidden; display: none;" src="javascript:&quot;<html><body style='background:transparent'></body></html>&quot;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking to the `collapseEmptyDivs` method - this should do what you want.

This page should tell you everything you need to know: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3072674?hl=en